# How do I prevent sharing contacts between two iPhones without opening a new account?

Tags: icloud, iphone

I have two iPhones, one is a 4s and the other is a 5s. One is for work and the other is personal.

How can I prevent sharing contacts between each without opening a new iCloud account for each?

Answer (score 1):

Having

- several iOS/OS X devices signed in to the same iCloud account
- contact syncing enabled in the respective settings

*always* syncs your contacts on all these devices (that's what iCloud syncing is all about in a way).

In your situation you could

- disable syncing of Contacts e.g. on the business iPhone (in Settings)
- create different contact groups for private and business contacts and then just use those on the respective phones (all contacts would still be synced though)
- create a separate iCloud account for the business iPhone (which actually might have other benefits depending on your employment status, who payed for the phone and the mobile contract etc.)